# After second slide, next slide not scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to horizontal scroll by mouse wheel only and div will snap to edge or center means on one scroll one slide go and next slide come in view. So I searched and found - https://codepen.io/vasiluca/pen/xWEQdQ?editors=0010 -I used and did some changes. First and Second slide scroll well but next slides not scroll by mouse wheel.

Jq

```
var scrolling = false;
    var scrolled = 0;
    const scrollDuration = 400;
    const scrollPause = 0; // Sets how much you must scroll before changing the slide
    // const scrollInterval = 5; // Time (seconds) before you can scroll again
    
    function scroll(direction) {
        if (scrolling == false) {
            scrolling = true;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollLeft: direction == 'left' ? $('html,body').scrollLeft() - $('.slide').innerWidth() : $('html,body').scrollLeft() + $('.slide').innerWidth()
            }, scrollDuration, function() {
                scrolling = false;
            });
        }
    }
    
    $(document).scrollTop(0);
    $(window).on('wheel', function(e) {
        if (scrolling == false) {
            scrolled++;
        }
        if (scrolled > scrollPause) {
            if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) { // scrolling down
                scroll('left');
                scrolled = 0;
            }
            if (e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) { // scrolling up
                scroll('right');
                scrolled = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    
    $('.slide').mouseover(function() {
        if (scrolling == false) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollLeft: $(this).offset().left
            }, 100);
        }
    });
    
    $('.left').click(function() {
        scroll('left');
        scrolled = 0;
    });
    $('.right').click(function() {
        scroll('right');
        scrolled = 0;
    });
    
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollLeft() == 0) {
            $('.left').css({
                'opacity': 0,
                'transform': 'translateX(-100%)'
            })
        } else {
            $('.left').css({
                'opacity': 1,
                'transform': 'translateX(0)'
            })
        }
        if ($(document).scrollLeft() == $('.slide-container').innerWidth() + $('.slide').innerWidth()) {
            $('.right').css({
                'opacity': 0,
                'transform': 'translateX(100%)'
            })
        } else {
            $('.right').css({
                'opacity': 1,
                'transform': 'translateX(0)'
            })
        }
    });
    
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 39:
            case 40:
            scroll('right');
            break;
            case 37:
            case 38:
            scroll('left');
            break;
        }
    });
```

CSS

```
body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    *{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    
    .container {border: 1px solid yello;}
    .horizontal{
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    .header{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100vw;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid yellow;
    }
    
    .left {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: background 0.15s ease;
        opacity 0.5s ease;
        transform 0.5s ease;
        }
    .left:hover{background: lightgrey;}
    
    .right{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        transition: background 0.15s ease;
    }
    .right:hover{background: lightgrey}
    
    .slide-container{
        display: flex;
        height: 100vh;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .slide{
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 50px;
        line-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(odd){
        background: limegreen;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(even){
        background: lightblue;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="continer">
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="title"> Horizontal Scrolling </h1>
        <span>(Use Mousewheel)</span>
    </div>
    
    <span class="left">left</span>
    <span class="right">right</span>
    
    <div class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">A</div>
        <div class="slide">B</div>
        <div class="slide">C</div>
        <div class="slide">D</div>
        <div class="slide">E</div>
    </div>
</div><!--continer ends here-->
```

Comment: I tried your code in Firefox and Chrome and it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please check, there are 5 slides and it works for only two slides A and B, And mouse wheel scroll not works for next slide C, D E.

Comment: I've checked it on Edge, Chrome, Firefox and IE11 on Windows10 with a mousewheel and it works perfectly - 5 slides both forward and back. What browser/OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the problem as the mousewheel is moving between slides OK at least on current browser (Edge on Windows10) but I put the code from the question up here as a snippet so others can easily try it in other environments.

```js
var scrolling = false;
    var scrolled = 0;
    const scrollDuration = 400;
    const scrollPause = 0; // Sets how much you must scroll before changing the slide
    // const scrollInterval = 5; // Time (seconds) before you can scroll again
    
    function scroll(direction) {
        if (scrolling == false) {
            scrolling = true;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollLeft: direction == 'left' ? $('html,body').scrollLeft() - $('.slide').innerWidth() : $('html,body').scrollLeft() + $('.slide').innerWidth()
            }, scrollDuration, function() {
                scrolling = false;
            });
        }
    }
    
    $(document).scrollTop(0);
    $(window).on('wheel', function(e) {
        if (scrolling == false) {
            scrolled++;
        }
        if (scrolled > scrollPause) {
            if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) { // scrolling down
                scroll('left');
                scrolled = 0;
            }
            if (e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) { // scrolling up
                scroll('right');
                scrolled = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    
    $('.slide').mouseover(function() {
        if (scrolling == false) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollLeft: $(this).offset().left
            }, 100);
        }
    });
    
    $('.left').click(function() {
        scroll('left');
        scrolled = 0;
    });
    $('.right').click(function() {
        scroll('right');
        scrolled = 0;
    });
    
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollLeft() == 0) {
            $('.left').css({
                'opacity': 0,
                'transform': 'translateX(-100%)'
            })
        } else {
            $('.left').css({
                'opacity': 1,
                'transform': 'translateX(0)'
            })
        }
        if ($(document).scrollLeft() == $('.slide-container').innerWidth() + $('.slide').innerWidth()) {
            $('.right').css({
                'opacity': 0,
                'transform': 'translateX(100%)'
            })
        } else {
            $('.right').css({
                'opacity': 1,
                'transform': 'translateX(0)'
            })
        }
    });
    
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 39:
            case 40:
            scroll('right');
            break;
            case 37:
            case 38:
            scroll('left');
            break;
        }
    });
```

```css
body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    *{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    
    .container {border: 1px solid yello;}
    .horizontal{
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    .header{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100vw;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid yellow;
    }
    
    .left {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: background 0.15s ease;
        opacity 0.5s ease;
        transform 0.5s ease;
        }
    .left:hover{background: lightgrey;}
    
    .right{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        transition: background 0.15s ease;
    }
    .right:hover{background: lightgrey}
    
    .slide-container{
        display: flex;
        height: 100vh;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .slide{
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 50px;
        line-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(odd){
        background: limegreen;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(even){
        background: lightblue;
    }
HTML
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="continer">
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="title"> Horizontal Scrolling </h1>
        <span>(Use Mousewheel)</span>
    </div>
    
    <span class="left">left</span>
    <span class="right">right</span>
    
    <div class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">A</div>
        <div class="slide">B</div>
        <div class="slide">C</div>
        <div class="slide">D</div>
        <div class="slide">E</div>
    </div>
</div><!--continer ends here-->
```

Comment: Which browser and operating system are you using?

Comment: It is perfect. But why it not working in my browser. I use windows 10 and latest versions of chrome and Firefox and edge. To confirm above code, I also tried on codepan but not works - https://codepen.io/ramesh_a/pen/oNzBxdd?editors=1001 - Please see.

Comment: Your codepen doesn't have jquery loaded - can you fix that and I'll have another go at it.

Comment: Yes, I added jquery in my codepan and it works but still on my desktop browser, it not working. I also tried link of jquery in my html file.

Comment: The codepen works for me. What desktop browser are you using and are you saying the codepen does not work on it? Do you mean not so much the browser but code that you are serving from your desktop rather than from the web?

Comment: Yes. codepen works from the web. But my local html file which is saved on my desktop and opened it, not works, even I tried jquery link (copied from your codepen) in my local html file (Before that I used jquery-3.2.1.min). Sorry for my English.